# Flatten Java Futures

Tags: java, java-8, future

I have two functions that each return `CompletebleFuture<Boolean>` instances and I want to `or` them into a single ordered and short-circuit-able future.

```
public CompletableFuture<Boolean> doA();
public CompletableFuture<Boolean> doB();
```

The non-future code (i.e. returning only booleans) would simply be

```
return doA() || doB();
```

Using Futures I have reached this point, when the return type is a `CompletableFuture<CompletableFuture<Boolean>>` instance.

```
doA.thenApply(b -> {
  if (!b) {
    return doB();
  } else {
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(b);
  }
}
```

Is there a way to flatten this? Or, any way I can make a return type of `CompletablyFuture<Boolean>`?

Edit: Note, being able to short circuit the futures is a feature that I want. I know that I'm then running the computations in serial, but that's ok. I ***do not*** want to run `doB` when `doA` returns true.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenAcceptBoth-java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage-java.util.function.BiConsumer- Does it work?

Comment: No. I don't want to execute the second computation if the first returns true. Using `thenAcceptBoth` would execute both, and by also returning a `CompletableFuture<Void>` it means that I've then lost the result

Comment: Does it mean doA and doB could be ran in the same thread?

Comment: In my specific case both calls will produce Futures backed by the same executor, so it's quite possible that they will run in the same thread. However, it will be two separate executions, with no communication between the processes, so there's no relevance that I can see to the threads that each runs in

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the method `thenCompose` instead of `thenApply`:

```
CompletableFuture<Boolean> result = doA().thenCompose(b -> b
    ? CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Boolean.TRUE) : doB());
```

Comment: maybe use `applyToEither` to use the result of `doA` in `doB`

Answer (score 4):

If the creation of the nested future is beyond your control, you can flatten it like this:

```
static <T> CompletableFuture<T> flatten(
  CompletableFuture<CompletableFuture<T>> nestedFuture) {
    return nestedFuture.thenCompose(Function.identity());
}
```